cx_Oracle не вызывает исключений при проблемах с IO на стороне БД
Друзья, может кто сталкивался с такой проблемой, при перегрузках по I/O на стороне БД Oracle, cx_Oracle вместо исключения выдает пустые результаты при выполнении запросов.

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Во-первых они там пишут, что у них новая крупная версия вышла под другим названием. Попробуйте сначала на неё перейти. https://oracle.github.io/python-oracledb/
